# How to prevent an <ol> to be generated

Tags: xslt

How can I ELEGANTLY prevent an <ol> to be generated if a group is empty:
I have this (ugly) code:

```
  ......
  </a>
  <xsl:if test="not(empty(current-group() except current-group()[1]))">
  <ol>
    <xsl:for-each select="current-group() except current-group()[1]">
      <li>
        ....
      </li>
    </xsl:for-each>
   </ol>
   </xsl:if>
   ....
```

Comment: What is inelegant about the current code? I can't see an issue with how this is done

Comment: Also, your closing tag shouldn't have any attributes.

Comment: Thanks for your comment: I find it inelegant to first do a check, and then loop. Would be better to do something like a WHILE loop, which would not execute at all if the group would be empty. Now the except-thingy has to be done twice.

Comment: closing tag: indeed: is typo. thnx

Answer (score 1):

you can use `xsl:choose`

```
<xsl:choose>
    <xsl:when test="">
         <!-- with <ol> -->
    </xsl:when>
    <xsl:otherwise>
         <!-- without <ol> -->
    </xsl:otherwise>
</xsl:choose>
```

Answer (score 1):

You could simplify the `test` to just

```
<xsl:if test="current-group()[2]">
```

since this will be an empty sequence (treated as false) for singleton groups.

Or declare a variable to avoid the code duplication:

```
<xsl:variable name="listItems" select="current-group()[position() gt 1]"/>
<xsl:if test="$listItems">
  <ol>
    <xsl:for-each select="$listItems">
      ...
```

Answer (score 1):

Very few languages will have what you need for the simple fact that you are looking at three conditions.

```
If there are things put something at the start
For each thing do an action
If there are things put something at the end
```

The only language that has anything approximating this is Django with its `for ... empty` syntax, but even then it isn't the same.

```
<ul>
{% for athlete in athlete_list %}
    <li>{{ athlete.name }}</li>
{% empty %}
    <li>Sorry, no athletes in this list.</li>
{% endfor %}
</ul>
```

With your example the best logic if you only want that list to appear when there are items is what you have done, with the suggestions by Ian Roberts.

To do what you are asking would require something like:

```
<xsl:wierd-for-each select="current-group() except current-group()[1]">
  <xsl:wrapper-element name="ol" />
  <xsl:looped-things>
    <li>
      ....
    </li>
  <xsl:looped-things>
</xsl:for-each>
```

Performing the `looped-things` and then inserting it into a create element if the loop was executed. The more pragmatic way is as you've done, to wrap the loop in an `<ol>` and then wrap that in an `<xsl:if>` if needed.